# Unable to start pod - context deadline exceeded error

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

We are currently trying to launch a pod on our kubernetes cluster.
The pod get stuck in the `Waiting` state (`ContainerCreating` reason) forever.

When getting details about the pod (`kubectl describe pod pod01`), the only event that's present is:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason      Age                     From     Message
  ----     ------      ----                    ----     -------
  Warning  FailedSync  2m29s (x439 over 125m)  kubelet  error determining status: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
```

From the various posts I found on the web, it can possibly mean that kubelet timing out while trying to contact etcd.

Is that correct?
How could I troubleshoot that further?

Thanks in advance,

Emmanuel

Comment: Have you checked kubelet logs?

Comment: Try checking the kubelet logs of the node where the pods try to schedule ```journalctl -u kubelet```.

Then *cordon* the node, making it UNSCHEDULE and try to deploy the Pod again; we expect it on the other nodes to work as you say.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#interacting-with-nodes-and-cluster

Finally restart the node in a safe way for your applications, by performing a *drain* first.

Comment: @glv after a cordon/drain/reboot/uncordon, I get quite a lot of " kubelet... transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"" which, if I'm correct, not to worry about

Comment: Well, I hope the problem is gone!